# NEXT.JS - Error: Export encountered errors on following paths: /blogs/:post

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I try to `next export` :

> Error occurred prerendering page "/blogs/[post]". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
> Error: Error for page /blogs/[post]: pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported. See more info here: https://err.sh/next.js/gssp-export
> at Object.exportPage [as default] (C:_PROJECT\bimeshow-master-27-02-1400\node_modules\next\dist\export\worker.js:15:254)
> info  - undefined (33/33)
> Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /blogs/[post]
> at exportApp (C:_PROJECT\bimeshow-master-27-02-1400\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:24:1103)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

blogs/[post].js:

```
...
export const getServerSideProps = async ({params}) => {
    const postUrl = params.post;
    const res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `/blog/single2?seo_url=${encodeURI(postUrl)}`
    });

    return { 
        props: { 
            data:res!=undefined? res.data.data : []
        }
    }
  }
```

routes.js:

```
module.exports = () => {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/about-us': { page: '/about-us' },
      '/404': { page: '/404' },
      '/login': { page: '/login' },
      '/blogs':{ page : '/blogs'},
      '/blogs/[post]': {page: '/blogs/[post]'},
    }
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const { parse } = require('url');

const DEV = process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== 'production';
const PORT = 4567;

const app = next({dir: '.', dev: DEV});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const getRoutes = require('./routes');

const routes = getRoutes();
  app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
      const route = routes[pathname];
      if (route) {
        return app.render(req, res, route.page, route.query);
      }
      return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> READY FOR LIFOTFF http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the information from the Link in the Error-Message already states: The getServerSideProps is not compatible with next export. You would need to change this to getStaticProps.

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/gssp-export

Here is the Documentation to getStaticProps:

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

Comment: getStaticProps is used for static pages and cannot display new posts after export. I need dynamic pages for this reason.

Comment: Then why would you go for a static site export at all? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: How do I usually have a dynamic output? I need [post] .js to be a dynamic page with good SEO.

Comment: I have had to do this in the past, and the best way is to use server side rendering. You will have to deploy the website as a serverless application (best option in my opinion). To lead the props in correctly on the server-side you will need to use getServerSideProps as you already are doing.

I have chosen to go with Vercel for an easy deployment, but i have experience doing this with docker aswell. Youll need to run the app with next start